react-native expo api routes singleton
I'm trying to implement a database using the new expo api routes. Long story short, each api is isolated and is unable to share the instance or connection between each other.
I've come up with a minimally reproducible example to demonstrate how the singleton pattern doesn't work between apis. I've also looked into the express export method but the exported code is minified / obfuscated so I can't really modify that easily or reliably after making changes.
api-utils/single.ts
let data: string | undefined;

export const setData = (newData: string) => {
  data = newData;
};
export const getData = () => {
  return data;
};

app/api/one+api.ts
import { getData } from "@/api-utils/single";
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  setData("New Data");
  return Response.json({ msg: "set new data value" });
}

app/api/two+api.ts
import { getData } from "@/api-utils/single";
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return Response.json({ msg: getData() });
}

Steps:

Visit /api/one  this will set the data
Now visit /api/two this should retrieve the set data but its just an empty object because data is undefined.

If anyone has any suggestions or alternative methods that might work please let me know.
